# Virtual keyboard is no longer working after an update to Chrome v50

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

We use the jQuery.keyboard plugin to get a virtual on screen keyboard.
Recently, in some formfields the characters entered were immediately removed again by the keyboard script.
We have traced the problem to the latest update of Chrome (v.50, or 50.0.2661.75).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that in the latest version of Chrome the maxlength value for a formfield is returned as -1, if there is no maxlength defined.

The script was checking if the maxlength was false, and ofcourse -1 is *true*, not *false* if evaluated.

It seems that in earlier versions of Chrome a missing maxlength attribute would evaluate to something "falsy". I haven't checked in earlier versions, but I suspect that a missing maxlength value would return "undefined" or 0.